# Magento 2: 301 Redirects

Tags: magento2, url, 301-redirect

How would I create 301 redirects from my old domain URLs to my new M2 site URLs?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

- In the .htaccess or VirtualHost configuration of Apache or nginx
- A Router observer in Magento that maps a regex of particular patterns to rewrite to the new Magento location from your legacy application's URL
- Create records in the `core_url_rewrite` table

Answer (score 0):

This function is built into Magento2 already, guide below:

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-write-redirect-301-rules-for-magento-2.html